# Canonical momentum operators in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What is the quantum canonical momentum operator corresponding to arbitrary canonical position. For example, in Cartesian coordinates ($x^i$), the canonical momentum operator with respect to each $x^i$ is $-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. For arbitrary canonical coordinates $q^i$, would the corresponding canonical momentum operators just be $-i\hat{\mathbf q}^i\cdot\hbar \nabla$?

Comment: In general, there is nothing such as "the" unique canonical momentum for a coordinate $q^i$. A canonical momentum is defined in such a way that its commutator with $q^i$ is nonzero, but it is zero for other $q$'s. One may redefine the momenta and coordinates in many ways, the so-called canonical transformations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformations , without changing the commutator. The idea that one always has a unique one-to-one map is OK to count the degrees of freedom but it's fundamentally flawed if one wants to study the full physical system.

Comment: Please define what you mean by $\hat{\mathbf q}^i$. Does your manifold have a metric? Moreover, $-i\hat{\mathbf q}^i\cdot\hbar \nabla$ has unusual "index up", where momentum $p_i$ traditionally has "index down". I recommend you to simply write $-i\hbar\nabla_{i}$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [curvilinear coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) you basically need to transform your derivatives likewise, ie, you need to use the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the coordinate transformation you used to go from Cartesian coords to the curvilinear system you have at hands.

More generally, you can think in terms of Quantum Mechanics over a curved manifold, in which case you would simply use the [covariant derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative).

Comment: There isn't a unique covariant derivative on a manifold! So which one?

Comment: @MBN generally one works with a metric compatible connection, i.e. $\nabla g_{\mu\nu} = 0$. Given a metric, this equation determines the corresponding connection.

Comment: @Deepak: I know that there is unique such connection (plus the condition to be trosion free). The question is not about manifolds with a choice of metric, so the answer should say something about it, otherwise it is incomplete and misleading.

Comment: @MBN: the last equation in the question has an inner product, which led me to believe that i could make some "general Physical assumptions", such as the existence of a metric and of a metric-compatible connection.

Comment: Fair enough.